# How to get post by categories without page load in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to get post by categories without page load in wordpress.

```
      $.get(
        {
          'action'   : 'get_post_title',
          'cat_id'   : catid,
      'pathname' : pathname,
          'url'      : 'new.php'
        }, 
        function( response )
        {
          $('#columns').html(response).hide().fadeIn(2000);
          $("#column").hide();
        },  "html" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First creat a function in function.php file
and ajax url is admin-ajax.php

```
$.get( ajax_request_url,
{
  'action'   : 'get_post_title',
  'cat_id'   : catid,
  'pathname' : pathname
}, 
function( response )
{
  $('#columns').html(response).hide().fadeIn(2000);
  $("#column").hide();
},  "html" );
```